# Generating Cell combination (By sizes) on grid using pathfinding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

I'm working on a project and as part of my process, I need to generate all the possible cell combination for given start point while avoiding the invalid cells (The cells filled with black. see down below).

The grid is NxM and each cell can have different width and height.
The cell combination shape should not exceed the max Height and Width.

How can I efficiently generate all the combinations (or Only the biggest) for each position? (the grid can be huge).

We are able to go in 4 directions. (up, right, bottom, left)

Example:

[image]

S is the start cell. and the goal is to find all the possible cell combinations that can be placed (without exceeding the maximum width and height).
In this example MAX_WIDTH - 4, MAX_HEIGHT - 7.

One option could be:

[image]

Another option:
[image]

and so on..

My Idea is to use a pathfinding algorithm such as Dijkstra or A*.
(Each Node is the cell) and the end goal is when we exceed to maximum lengths.
I should take into account the option that maybe I'll need to give a score for shape (by the number of vertices etc...)

I tried to go each direction with DFS, but it's working only on small grids.

My Code:

```
public class CombinationCreator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The grid that contain 2D array of cells.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Grid _grid; 
    /// <summary>
    /// Current state of the cell combination shape, used in the recursive function.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Cell> CurrentState { get; set; } = new List<Cell>();

    /// <summary>
    /// List of directions used for scanning the cells.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<(int row, int column)> Directions = new List<(int row, int column)>()
    {
        (0, 1), // right
        (1, 0), // bottom
        (0, -1), // left
        (-1, 0) // top
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// List of all the possible combinations.
    /// </summary>
    public List<List<Cell>> Results { get; set; } = new List<List<Cell>>();

    public CombinationCreator(Grid grid)
    {
        _grid = grid;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get i , j indexes of the cell. (will be the starting index)
    /// </summary>
    public List<List<Cell>> GetCombinations(int i, int j)
    {
        double MAX_WIDTH = 4;
        double MAX_HEIGHT = 7;
        List<List<Cell>> result = new List<List<Cell>>;
        return GenerateCombination(i, j, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursive function to generate all the possible cell combinations by scanning the grid.
    /// </summary>
    private void GenerateCombinations(int i, int j, double maxWidth, double maxHeight, int depth = 0, double minX = double.MaxValue,
        double maxX = double.MinValue, double minY = double.MaxValue, double maxY = double.MinValue)
    {
        if (depth > 50)
        { // to prevent Infinite Recursion
            return;
        }

        if (ShouldSavePreviousState(i, j, maxWidth, maxHeight, minX, maxX, minY, maxY))
        { // If the current cell will exceed maxWidth and maxHeight then we need to save the previous state.
            Results.Add(new List<Cell>(CurrentState));
        }
        else
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < _grid.Cells.GetLength(0) &&
                j >= 0 && j < _grid.Cells.GetLength(1))
            {
                Cell currentCell = _grid.Cells[i, j];

                if (!currentCell.Marked && currentCell.Valid && !currentCell.IsUsed)
                {
                    currentCell.Marked = true;
                    CurrentState.Add(currentCell);

                    minX = Math.Min(minX, currentCell.TopLeft.x);
                    maxX = Math.Max(maxX, currentCell.BottomRight.x);
                    minY = Math.Min(minY, currentCell.BottomRight.y);
                    maxY = Math.Max(maxY, currentCell.TopLeft.y);

                    foreach (var direction in Directions)
                    { // Go each direction
                        int newRow = i + direction.row;
                        int newCol = j + direction.column;

                        GenerateCombinations(newRow, newCol, maxWidth, maxHeight, depth + 1, minX, maxX, minY, maxY);
                    }

                    CurrentState.RemoveAt(CurrentState.Count - 1);
                    currentCell.Marked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the current cell will exceed maxWidth and maxHeight or the cell is the boundaries.
    /// then we need to save the previous state.
    /// </summary>
    private bool ShouldSavePreviousState(int i, int j, double maxWidth, double maxHeight, double minX = double.MaxValue,
        double maxX = double.MinValue, double minY = double.MaxValue, double maxY = double.MinValue)
    {
        double currentWidth = maxX - minX;
        double currentHeight = maxY - minY;

        if (i >= 0 && i < _grid.Cells.GetLength(0) &&
            j >= 0 && j < _grid.Cells.GetLength(1))
        {
            Cell currentCell = _grid.Cells[i, j];

            if (!currentCell.Marked && currentCell.Valid && !currentCell.IsUsed)
            {
                double nextMinX = Math.Min(minX, currentCell.TopLeft.x);
                double nextMaxX = Math.Max(maxX, currentCell.BottomRight.x);
                double nextMinY = Math.Min(minY, currentCell.BottomRight.y);
                double nextMaxY = Math.Max(maxY, currentCell.TopLeft.y);

                double nextWidth = nextMaxX - nextMinX;
                double nextHeight = nextMaxY - nextMinY;

                if (nextHeight > maxHeight || nextWidth > maxWidth)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (!currentCell.Valid || currentCell.IsUsed)
            {
                if (currentHeight > maxHeight || currentWidth > maxWidth)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Cell Class:

```
public class Cell
{
    public bool Marked { get; set; } // Indicates when already saw the cell during the scanning
    public bool Valid { get; set; } // Indicates if we can use the cell ( white cell ).
    public bool IsUsed { get; set; } // Indicates if another shape use this cell.
    public Point TopLeft { get; set; } // The top left point
    public Point BottomRight { get; set; } // The bottom right point
}
```

Comment: @ravenspoint thanks for your comments. 
I used the polyomino shape in a manner of cells combination.

Comment: "I tried to go each direction with DFS, but it's working only on small grids."  This seems to be a sensible approach.  Maybe breadth first would be more efficient, but the end result should be the same either way.  Please provide an example of the smallest grid where your algorithm stops working and show the input data and what exactly happens.

Comment: @ravenspoint
 So how should I call it? (rather than polyomino)

Comment: Yes, I still Interest... Actually, I saw your code and I'm trying to run it.

Answer (score 0):

While this may well be soluble using graph theory, a more straightforward approach is to tackle it using computational geometry.

An algorithm to enumerate valid ( as specified in question ) cell combinations:

```
- LOOP CA over cells
   - Create E, a rectangle of maximum combination size,
          located with top right at top right of cell CA
   - IF start cell not completely included inside E
         - CONTINUE to next CA cell
   - CLEAR current combination
   - LOOP CB over cells
       - IF CB completely included inside E AND not forbidden
           - Add cell CB to current combination
   - Add current combination to list of combinations
```

For this input

```
    myGrid.setVert({0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2});
    myGrid.setHorz({0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2});
    myGrid.setForbid({{5, 2}});
    myGrid.setStartCell({4, 4});
    myGrid.setMaxCombSize({6, 7});
```

The list of cell combinations is

```
12 valid cell combinations found
2 1, 3 1, 4 1, 2 2, 3 2, 4 2, 2 3, 3 3, 4 3, 2 4, 3 4, 4 4,
3 1, 4 1, 3 2, 4 2, 3 3, 4 3, 3 4, 4 4,
4 1, 5 1, 4 2, 4 3, 5 3, 4 4, 5 4,
2 2, 3 2, 4 2, 2 3, 3 3, 4 3, 2 4, 3 4, 4 4,
3 2, 4 2, 3 3, 4 3, 3 4, 4 4,
4 2, 4 3, 5 3, 4 4, 5 4,
2 3, 3 3, 4 3, 2 4, 3 4, 4 4,
3 3, 4 3, 3 4, 4 4,
4 3, 5 3, 4 4, 5 4,
2 4, 3 4, 4 4, 2 5, 3 5, 4 5,
3 4, 4 4, 3 5, 4 5,
4 4, 5 4, 4 5, 5 5,
```

( Each row is a valid combination.  The number pairs are the zero-based column and row indices of combined cells. )

Here is a graphical display of the first combination

[image]

( The starting cell is indicated by "S", and the blue outlined cells are included in the combination. )

Here is the C++ code that does the enumeration

```
void cGrid::EnumerateCombinations()
{
    auto startCellDim = rectDim(myStartCell);

    // loop E over cells
    for (int rowE = 0; rowE < myHorz.size(); rowE++)
    {
        for (int colE = 0; colE < myVert.size(); colE++)
        {
            // create rectangle E of maximum combination size with E cell at top left
            auto Ecell = rectDim(std::make_pair(colE, rowE));
            rect_ltrb_t E{
                Ecell[0], Ecell[1],
                Ecell[0] + myMaxCombSize.first, Ecell[1] + myMaxCombSize.second};

            // check that E includes the start cell
            if (!isInside(startCellDim, E))
                continue;

            std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> comb;

            // loop over cells
            for (int row = 0; row < myHorz.size(); row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < myHorz.size(); col++)
                {
                    // if cell completely inside E and valid
                    auto cell = rectDim(std::make_pair(col, row));
                    if (isInside(cell, E) && (!isForbidden(std::make_pair(col, row))))
                    {
                        // add to current combination
                        comb.push_back(std::make_pair(col, row));
                    }
                }
            // add current combination to list
            myListComb.push_back(comb);
        }
    }
}
```

The C++ code for the complete application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so76407006  The application displays the cell combination with the largest total area.  The user can advance the display through other valid combinations in order of decreasing area.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your time! 
I saw your repository and I tries to run and debug it to understand it better. unfortunately, I didn't succeed.
Although I cloned your "Windex" repository.
Another thing, My shape can be like the "polyomino" shape not only rectangles.

Comment: Note that any cell combination that is valid but not rectangular is going to be smaller than another valid combination which is rectangular - so we can ignore non rectangular combinations.  This also applies to rectangular combination that are have forbidden cells   removed.

Comment: I agree with you, so you suggest ignoring the forbidden cells for the enumeration and then removing them when we finish our shape?

Comment: Conceptually, that could be done.  However, if you look at the implementation code posted in my answer you will see that I handle the forbidden cells as we go along.  I have updated the pseudo code to handle forbidden cells.

Comment: FYI I have added a feature to read the grid spacings from an input text file

Comment: After I saw your approach, can you know to tell me how it will behave on a large grid?
And what is the time complexity?

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest version, you will be able to find out for yourself by inputting a grid of whatever size you want.